# What is wrong with my isPrime method?

Tags: java, function, methods, primes

This is my `isPrime` method:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i < num; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

I put `isPrime(9)` and it returns `true`. What is wrong with the method?

Comment: Because `i*i = 9`  and `9 < 9` is evaluated to `false`. So you never enter in  your for loop and hence you return `true`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your condition should be i * i <= num

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) 
{
        if (num == 2) 
            return true;
        if (num < 2 || num % 2 == 0) 
            return false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
            if (num % i == 0) 
                return false;
        return true;
}
```

You didn't take number 9 in your consideration so 9<9 will result false. But you need to check 9.

Comment: @ADG thanks for the hint .. but when the question was asked .. he want to fix specific bug in the code .. I didn't notice case when num=2

Comment: 1 is not a prime number, shall add `|| num == 1` to the second line on the function

Comment: @StellaLie Even more generically, numbers smaller than 2 are not prime.

Answer (score 5):

my sample:

```
public boolean isPrime(int x) {
    if (x==1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(x);i++) {
            if (x%i==0) return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 1 is not a prime number, adjust your sample.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8: (Example with lambda expression and streams)

```
public static boolean isPrimeFunctionalStyle(int number) {
    return number > 1 && 
            IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(number))
                .noneMatch(i -> number % i == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. The main bug is that you never check divisibility by `sqrt(num)` due to an off-by-one error in the loop.
2. The other bug is that you don't consider `2` to be prime (which it is).

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this ( check condition) :

```
 private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num == 2) return true;
        if (num % 2 == 0)
            return false;
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= num; i += 2)
            if (num % i == 0) return false;
        return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

(Late) Sidenode:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i < num; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This code is missing `2`; `2` is a primenumber. Everything dividable by `2` isn't, except the `2` - so, use:

```
private static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    if (num == 2) return true;
    if (num % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i * i < num; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would downvote for putting code with exactly same mistake OP had but I can't. There should be `i * i <= num`

Answer (score 0):

the loop condition with `i * i < num` should be `i * i <= num`

Answer (score 0):

the loop is never executed so it returns directly true

Answer (score 0):

The loop does not run. It gets terminated in the very first value of i because 3 x 3 = 9
it does not meet the condition i * i < n

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 3; i * i < num; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
```

`i * i` is 9, and 9 in not less than 9, thus for loop is not run.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use if and else statement to check to see if the number is prime. There is a pattern, all the numbers are either multiples of either 2 or 3 once your number reach certain limits.

```
public static boolean isPrime2 (int n)
{
    if (n == 1) {
        return false;
    } else if (n == 2 || n==3) {
        return true;
    } else if (n>2) {
        if(n % 2 ==0 || n % 3 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPrime (int number) {
    if(number < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    int check = (int) Math.sqrt(number);


    for(int i = 2; i <= check; i++) {
        if(number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package Prime;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime {
    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declare lower bound and upper bound variables and get their values
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Lower Bound number: ");
        int lowerBound = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter an Upper Bound number: ");
        int upperBound = scanner.nextInt();

        int counter;

        if ((lowerBound <= 0) || (upperBound <= 0)) {
            System.out.println("Bounds must be greater than 0, Invalid Bounds");
            } else if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
            System.out.println("Upper bound cannot be less than lower bound, Invalid Bounds\nProgram terminating.");
        } else {
            // loop from lower bound to upper bound
            System.out.println("The Prime numbers are: ");
            for (counter = lowerBound; counter <= upperBound;
                 counter++) {
                // if prime number, display in primeNumbersJTextArea
                if (isPrime(counter)) {
                    System.out.print(counter + ", ");
                }
            } // end for loop
        } // end else

    } // end method calculatePrimesJButtonActionPerformed


    // method to determine if a number is a Prime number?
    private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        // number 1 is not a Prime number
        if (number == 1)
            return false;

        int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(number);

        for (int counter = 2; counter <= limit; counter++) {
            if (number % counter == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```