# Getting the first 100 prime numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey so im trying to create a program that prints out the first 100 prime numbers. this is my code however it doesn't print out the first hundred but the primes from 2 to 100. what am i doing wrong here that make it print out only those ant not the first hundred?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Prime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxCount = 100;
    int[] values = new int[maxCount];
    int temp = 3;
    boolean prime = true;

    for (int j = 1; j < maxCount; ++j) {
      values[j] = j + 1;
      if (values[j] == 2) {
        System.out.println(values[j]);
      }
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < maxCount; ++j) {
      if (values[j] % 2 == 0)
        prime = false;
      else {
        boolean prime2 = true;
        double test = Math.sqrt(values[j]);
        int divisor = 3;
        while (prime2 && (divisor <= test)) {
          if (values[j] % divisor == 0) {
            prime2 = false;
          } else divisor += 2;
        }
        if (prime2)
          System.out.println(values[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code using correct indentation. Most people will not want to put in an effort to look at badly formatted code. It might be all the same to a compiler, but it is not to humans; and if you don't care enough, why should we?

Comment: what is the current output?

Comment: 2 3 5 711 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

Comment: I request not to believe that the number that could not be divided by **2** and **3** are prime number. Take an example of **119** which is not dividable by 2 & 3 but it can be divided by 7 and 13.

Comment: See this question where it identifies if the value is prime or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798391/java-isprime-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping until `j < maxCount` while you should loop until the number of elements in the array are equal to `maxCount`. For that you'll need another counter which is `val_cnt` in the following fixed code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Prime {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int maxCount = 100;
  int[] values = new int[maxCount];
  int temp = 3;
  int val_cnt = 0;
  values[val_cnt++] = 2;
  System.out.println(2);
  for (int j = 3; val_cnt < maxCount; ++j) {
   boolean prime = true;
   if (j % 2 == 0)
    prime = false;
   else {
    double test = Math.sqrt(j);
    int divisor = 3;
    while (prime && (divisor <= test)) {
     if (j % divisor == 0) {
      prime = false;
     } else divisor += 2;
    }
    if (prime) {
     values[val_cnt++] = j;
     System.out.println(j);
    }

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making your loop iterate till j becomes 100 , and at every iteration irrespective of whether a prime number has been found or not, j gets incremented.
So have something like:-

```
while(maxCount<100){

if(number_is_prime){
increment maxCount;
}
else{
continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating your loop till `100` only. But you want to print first 100 prime numbers, not prime numbers between 1 to 100. so every time the number is found to be a prime number just increment the `count`(which counts the number of prime numbers printed.) to `1` and exit from the loops when the `count` is `100`.Here is the simple approach for printing first 100 prime numbers:

```
 int count = 0,flag=0;
    for(int i=2;count<100;i++){
        flag = 0;
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
                flag ++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0){
            System.out.println(i);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only increase the value of `j` if prime number is found,

Re-format your codes same as this,

```
for (int j = 2; j < maxCount;) {
  if (values[j] % 2 == 0){
    prime = false;
    j++;
   }
  else {
    boolean prime2 = true;
    double test = Math.sqrt(values[j]);
    int divisor = 3;
    while (prime2 && (divisor <= test)) {
      if (values[j] % divisor == 0) {
        prime2 = false;
      } else divisor += 2;
    }
    if (prime2)
      System.out.println(values[j]);
      j++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
class PrimeNumbers {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i =0; int num =0; 
        String primeNumbers = ""; 
        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            int counter=0;   
           for(num =i; num>=1; num--) {
                 if(i%num==0) {
                      counter = counter + 1;
                 }   
            }    
            if (counter ==2) {  
                primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
            }
        }    
        System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to 100 are :");
        System.out.println(primeNumbers); 
    } 
}
```